# How to create a new Object instead of mutating it - javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

Here i am having a Object i.e `ApiData1` . Where it has `color` key value pair inside `properties` . I am changing the color values according to `ApiData2` value `numberOfProjects`, and having a range where `numberOfProjects` values lies between a set of range i am updating the `color` value. It is working fine. But after updating, I am setting this value in a state [React] . However on initial load color has updated and working fine. After a button click i am doing exactly this process with Different ApiData2 value. ApiData1 `color` value gets updated. But react doesn't detect the change.

I suspect because of mutating the `ApiData1` . Its not picking the prop change.Instead of mutating is there any way to create a new `ApiData1` value with it.  Anyway to recreate this logic.

Your help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the [WORKING DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanush1995/sta76yx5/)

```
let ApiData1 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        }
    ]
}

let ApiData2 = [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Tamil Nadu",
        code: "TN",
        latitude: 29.9964948,
        longitude: 81.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 10,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 1433,
        }
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Karnataka",
        code: "KA",
        latitude: 21.9964948,
        longitude: 82.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 11,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 3500,
        }
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Pondicherry",
        code: "PY",
        latitude: 22.9964948,
        longitude: 87.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 12,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 5500,
        }
    }
];

function updateColor() {
    function updateColorValue(colorJsonObject, colorValue) {
        let updatedProperties = {
            ...colorJsonObject.properties,
            color: colorValue
        };
        colorJsonObject.properties = updatedProperties;
        return { ...colorJsonObject };
    }

    let range = [
        {
            "Minimum": 1,
            "Maximum": 2000,
            "color": 1
        },
        {
            "Minimum": 2000,
            "Maximum": 4000,
            "color": 2
        },
        {
            "Minimum": 4000,
            "Maximum": 6000,
            "color": 3
        }
    ]

    ApiData1.features.map(colorObject =>
        ApiData2.map(apiData => {
            if (
                colorObject.properties.stateId === apiData.latestMetric.stateId
            ) {
                range.map(i => {
                    if (
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects >= i.Minimum &&
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects <= i.Maximum
                    ) {
                        updateColorValue(colorObject, i.color);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    );
    return ApiData1;
}

let colorValue = updateColor();

console.log(colorValue);
```

I have done something like this to create a newObject, instead of mutating it ,

```
  
     function updateProperties(colorJsonObject, colorValue) {
        let updatedProperties = {
            ...colorJsonObject.properties,
            color: colorValue
        };
        console.log(updatedProperties)
        return updatedProperties;
        
    }
    let newData = {...ApiData1}

    newData.features.map(colorObject =>
        ApiData2.map(apiData => {
            if (
                colorObject.properties.stateId === apiData.latestMetric.stateId
            ) {
                range.map(i => {
                    if (
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects >= i.Minimum &&
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects <= i.Maximum
                    ) {
                    
                            let value = updateProperties(colorObject, i.color)
                        return {...colorObject,properties:value}
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    );
    return newData;
}

let colorValue = updateColor();

console.log(colorValue);
```

value has been updating it on the `updateProperties` function , but it is not reflected in the newData object. still i am getting oldObject, not the new one.

[HERE IS THE LINK FOR THAT](https://jsfiddle.net/Dhanush1995/nmj8ysto/12/)

Comment: array::map returns a new array. All you've done is "copy" the old object, run a bunch of map functions on it, and returned the copy you made with old values.

Comment: hi, sry its little confusing for me, could u pls tell me , where i have to change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the result of `newData.map`. Also you don't need a nested map since all you want to operate on is a specific object.

What you need is to find that object and update it. Make use of `Array.prototype.find` to find the relevant matching object for state and then update it using the range array by looping over it

```js
let ApiData1 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 10,
                "stateId": 10,
                "name": "Tamil Nadu",
                "code": "TN"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 11,
                "stateId": 11,
                "name": "Karnataka",
                "code": "KA"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon"
            },
            "properties": {
                "color": 1,
                "id": 12,
                "stateId": 12,
                "name": "Pondicherry",
                "code": "PY"
            }
        }
    ]
}

let ApiData2 = [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Tamil Nadu",
        code: "TN",
        latitude: 29.9964948,
        longitude: 81.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 10,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 1433,
        }
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Karnataka",
        code: "KA",
        latitude: 21.9964948,
        longitude: 82.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 11,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 3500,
        }
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Pondicherry",
        code: "PY",
        latitude: 22.9964948,
        longitude: 87.6855882,
        latestMetric: {
            stateId: 12,
            year: 0,
            numberOfProjects: 5500,
        }
    }
];

function updateColor() {
    function updateColorValue(colorJsonObject, colorValue) {
        let updatedProperties = {
            ...colorJsonObject.properties,
            color: colorValue
        };
        colorJsonObject.properties = updatedProperties;
        return { ...colorJsonObject };
    }
    
     function updateProperties(colorJsonObject, colorValue) {
        let updatedProperties = {
            ...colorJsonObject.properties,
            color: colorValue
        };
        console.log(updatedProperties)
        return updatedProperties;
        
    }

    let range = [
        {
            "Minimum": 1,
            "Maximum": 2000,
            "color": 1
        },
        {
            "Minimum": 2000,
            "Maximum": 4000,
            "color": 2
        },
        {
            "Minimum": 4000,
            "Maximum": 6000,
            "color": 3
        }
    ]
    
    let newData = {
       ...ApiData1,
       features: ApiData1.features.map(colorObject => {
           const apiData = ApiData2.find(apiData => {
            if (
                colorObject.properties.stateId === apiData.latestMetric.stateId
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
          });
          let newValue;
          range.forEach(i => {
                    if (
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects >= i.Minimum &&
                        apiData.latestMetric.numberOfProjects <= i.Maximum
                    ) {
                    
                      let value = updateProperties(colorObject, i.color)
                        newValue = {...colorObject,properties:value}
                    }
                });
           return newValue;
       })
    }

    
    return newData;
}

let colorValue = updateColor();

console.log(colorValue);
```

Comment: Which objects position has changed?

Comment: Hi , in ApiData2 sometimes the latestMetric will come as null, like this

latestMetric:null,

 In this scenario ApiData1 value has to be remain same instead of removing it. Any idea of how to do that

Comment: sometimes the value may come or may not ,, on that scenario , the default ApiData1 values has to present. Any idea of how to do that